# Making Desktop smaller with an VB .Net Application

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio-2012

I want to make an Application that is placed on the Top of my Desktop. There I will place the Tools I want.

My Question is: is it possible that, when the Application is docked on the top, and other applications are maximized, they shouldn't be over / under my strip on the Top.

The Desktop should be "smaller", I hope I was clear enough- if not, i can be more specifically.

I work with VS 2012 and VB .NET.

Comment: Raymond Chen's classic [What if two programs did this?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx) comes to mind (although the example there is "How do I create a window that is never covered by any other windows, not even other topmost windows?", it seems similar)

Comment: Google "vb.net shappbarmessage" to find sample code and libraries.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean forcing your application to stay on top at all times ?

If so this is how you do it

```
Me.TopMost = True
```

That will keep you current form on top

Comment: topmost causes, that when other applications are maximized, my application will be always on top. What I want is something else - if you place your taskbar on the right and you maximize some other window, then this window wont be under the tasklbar, but near it... my strip application should do the same...

Comment: modal is not the same as topmost - please edit your answer to avoid confusion